# Custom SQL Error Page on Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have a question about Zend Framework. I have advancing ErrorController which is executing eg. when someone enter on invalid page. There is error page (with styles etc.) that I've created myself.

Now, I want to make more friendly error page when SQL Error exists. SQL error it means more important error such as SQLSTATE[28000][1045] Access denied for user ....
 or [SQL STATE: TO MANY CONNECTIONS.

Take a look at it:

http://images67.fotosik.pl/700/5433d28579f69289gen.png

As you can see, it's totally unfriendly page with useless error for normal user. Does it's possible to make custom error page with this kind of errors or catch it and redirect after show this page?

Thanks for the reply, grettings

Comment: Could you post some more information and code snippets, and maybe demonstrate more clearly what is happening and what you'd like to happen? I kinda understand your question but remain a bit confused.

Comment: @Jordan, I've tried explain more about my problem. In this moment I'm using ErrorController which is based on  case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ROUTE:
    Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_CONTROLLER:
            case Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler::EXCEPTION_NO_ACTION:
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);
                $this->view->message = 'Page not found';
                break;
            default:
                $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(500);
                $this->view->message = 'Zend error'

Comment: thanks all for replies.